# Detecting a present signature in a Word 2007 document using VSTO

Tags: c#, .net, vba, vsto, signature

I'm trying to detect a present signature in a Word document with VSTO. I am stuck, because one I don't have much experience with VSTO and second I can't find any documentation about this.

**What did I develop so far?**

1. Created a Ribbon Add-In for Word 2007, with two buttons.
2. Created methods for handling the clicked buttons.
3. When Start Debugging, Word opens with a document which include a Signature Line(locally stored document).

**Where did I get stuck?**

I've tried to figure out which properties are involved with Signature. Some code:

```
Word.Application wa = this.applicationObject;
Word.Document doc   = wa.ActiveDocument;
SignatureSet ss     = doc.Signatures;
```

As a result the SignatureSet remains empty, while there is a present Signature Line. The count property is always 0.

What should be fixed or done to get a working IsDocumentSigned Method?

All kind of tips and tricks are pleased to see :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Farrell found an answer for this question on the MSDN forums, here is the link if anyone is interested.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/f032a616-ee63-424b-b56d-1e495e241b0e

Comment: Yes indeed, but the question  is not totally answered. Unfortunately there's no option to get the real SignatureLine object. But read the topic, it's helpful to understand the problem.